# Change the placeholder text of an input field after initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder, mapbox

I am working with an input field that is generated on a map. I would like to change the placeholder text of the input field from "Search" to "Search for Location".

The input field does not have a class or id but its parents do. I tried changing after initializing using jQuery below to no avail.

```
$('.leaflet-control-mapbox-geocoder-form input').attr("placeholder","Search for Location");
```

Below is a fiddle with the input field visible. I am happy to continue using jQuery or via pure JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/teraw600/

Comment: May I know where you put the code? I had amended your code [http://jsfiddle.net/teraw600/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/teraw600/1/)  for testing, it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't working in your example because jQuery wasn't included.

If you don't want to use jQuery, you could use the following:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dkjz6mf8/)

```
document.querySelector('.leaflet-control-mapbox-geocoder-form input').placeholder = "Search for Location";
```

---

You can also add an event listener for the `ready` event and then change the `placeholder` attribute within the callback. Again, no jQuery needed:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wpesoo31/)

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3BheWNlIiwiYSI6IlNIMnRfZ2MifQ.SreIfdJljzEj2M033UubsA';
L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.h186knp8')
    .addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl(
        'mapbox.places', {
            keepOpen: true
        }
    ))
    .addEventListener('ready', function () {
        document.querySelector('.leaflet-control-mapbox-geocoder-form input').placeholder = "Search for Location";
    }
);
```

Answer (score 8):

A better way to do it would be to add a key value pair(placeholder: ***your text***) to the geocoder object like so when you initialize it:

```
  var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
    placeholder: 'Search for Location'
  });
```